# Shared preferences to save complete activity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am creating one app where in offline demo of that app I want to save complete activity so that when user will open app again it will get last changes made on that activity. My activity contain 2 seekbar , 1 toggle button , 1 Number Picker so my question is instead of using shared preferences for every view can I use it for complete activity.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can not save a complete Activity. What's wrong with using shared prefs, you only have 4 values?

Comment: You simply cant save a complete Activity, that would be wrong for many reasons. You also cant use savedinstancestate because it will not work for your need, "when user will open app again it will get last changes made on that activity". However you should use shared preferences, but you will have to save view by view.

Answer (score 0):

save the data to Bundle
use the below method

`protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }`